# Modified the object properties of an array, but not changed on page

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, watch

I have a problem when using vue + typescript to write a simple demo.

#### vue code

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="user in users" v-on:click="clickUser(user)" class="user">
                {{user}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    type User = {
        name: string,
        clicked?: boolean
    }

    @Component
    export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
        @Prop() private users: Array<User> = [{name: "Mike"}, {name: "Ann"}];

        clickUser(user: User) {
            user.clicked = true
            alert("clicked on " + user.name + ": " + user.clicked)
        }
    }
</script>
```

They display on page:

```
* { "name": "Mike" }
* { "name": "Ann" }
```

When I click on Ann, it will alert with:

```
clicked on Ann: true
```

But nothing changed on the page. I expect the row `* { "name": "Ann" }` to be `* { "name": "Ann", "clicked": true }`

How to fix it?

A complete small demo for this: https://github.com/freewind-demos/vue-modify-array-object-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that while your are adding the new key/value pair to a reactive object, the pair itself it not reactive as Vue cannot detect a new property being added to a **reactive** object. You need to use the `Vue.set(target,key,value)` method here.  So change your `user.clicked` assignment in your `clickUser()` method like below.  It should magically begin to work!

```
    clickUser(user: User) {
        Vue.set(user,'clicked',true)
        alert("clicked on " + user.name + ": " + user.clicked)
    }
```

More here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set  & here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

This does seem a little counter intuitive at times because if you were to instead of modifying the user, add a completely new one `this.users.push({"name":"John"})` it works. But with one you are creating a new reactive object, while with the other you are modifying an existing one.

Comment: @Thanks for the fix and also the explanation!